# How can I replicate behaviour of go-to command? (42gg, 42G)

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript, functions, command

I've been searching far and wide around tutorials, :help command, source code, Stacks but maybe I just can't form my query correctly in the vimscript lingo.
My goal is to have a short command for switching buffers like:
`42B` or `B42` that will switch the view to 42nd buffer. I don't want to monkey-map all the series `B1`, `B2`, `B3` ..., though. So I want to treat 42 as an argument to some underlying function that chooses the appropriate buffer.

Pls halp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There actually is a built-in map which does this, `<c-^>` or control+^

If you don't like this (it is indeed difficult to press), you can remap it simply.

```
nnoremap gb <c-^>
```

Note: I am using `gb` here since `B` is already a vim command.  You can use `B` if you really want, but be aware that you would be overriding a built-in.

I am also going to show how to make this map if there *weren't* already a command `<c-^>`.  Since there is an ex-command `:buffer N` which does what we need, the map would take the following pattern:

```
nnoremap <silent> gb :<c-u>buffer <c-r>=v:count<cr><cr>
```

The only tricky parts are `<c-u>` which eliminates the *line-oriented* address vim places after `:` by default and `<c-r>=v:count<cr>` which means enter the current *count* into the cmdline.

Comment: This is brilliant! Thank you so much. I'll definitely be using that. For the record, <c-^> chooses the buffer with that exact number and I wanted something more robust, that would be able to skip over the holes coming from closed buffers. But it's unnecessary complex and I can always just map `:bn` to something sensible...